# Stokes theorem: bounds of integration when z=k(x,y)

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

I am using Paul's Online Notes to practice Stokes theorem. Here is the link to the exact problem which is giving me trouble: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcIII/StokesTheorem/Prob4.aspx.

C is given in the problem as having "a counter clockwise rotation if you are above the triangle and looking down towards the xy-plane."

Here is a graph of C:
[graph of C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2iG9.gif)

Projecting C onto the xy-plane gives this:
[xy-projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GV3l.gif)

The arrows indicating orientation aren't in the projection; if they were, they would point from (4,0) up to (0,2) (or from the x-intercept up to the y-intercept).

I understand all aspects of the problem except for the bounds on the final double-integral.
My question is why the final double-integrals x bounds are from 0->4 and not from 4->0?

The line is oriented from right to left, so it does not make sense to integrate from left to right. Does projecting down onto the xy-plane change or negate the orientation somehow?

This is my first question on here: I appreciate feedback on how to improve this question or math questions in general.

Comment: The curve $C$ is oriented so that by the [right-hand-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Curve_orientation_and_normal_vectors) the normal vector of the plane through $P,Q,R$ points outward of the solid simplex. Stokes' theorem allows to calculate the line integral of $\vec F$ along that oriented curve as a surface integral over the surface $S$ enclosed by the curve $C$. All that matters is that the normal vector $\vec n$ must point outward. When we parametrize the surface we can clearly do that by $0\le x\le 4$ and $0\le y\le 2-\frac{1}{2}x$.

Comment: We just need coordinates $(x,y)$ that map to points on the surface $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand now! When computing this surface integral, the bounds of integration on the surface integral describe some 2D region, D.

That is, for some surface S and some 2D region D, the double integral over S DS is computed by converting it into the double integral over D DA (dxdy or dydx). This has nothing to do with stokes theorem! You can see this on step six and seven of the solution to the problem here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcIII/StokesTheorem/Prob4.aspx.